# What are cheaper alternatives to Adobe Illustrator on Windows, Mac, Linux?

Tags: windows, linux, mac, adobe-illustrator

*Background:* I'm mostly a Mac user and have tried out [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) and even created SVGs with it, but it is highly user-unfriendly, it uses CTRL as the modifier key. I found [VectorDesigner](http://www.tweakersoft.com/vectordesigner/) which seems promising so far. I also use Windows and Linux (Xubuntu and Ubuntu for desktop applications) so either of those would be great too.

So, finally: What are cheaper alternatives to [Adobe Illustrator](http://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator/) on Windows, Mac, Linux?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Mac, check out [Lineform](http://www.freeverse.com/mac/product/?id=6020) ($80 USD):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

i'm using **[Xara Extreme](http://www.xara.com/uk/products/xtreme/)** (and Xara 3D); user-friendly, fast and reasonably priced.

[image]

*for Windows $89, for Linux ([Xara LX](http://www.xaraxtreme.org/?task=view)) $0*

Comment: This looks pretty good! Will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Xara Xtreme](http://www.xaraxtreme.org/). It's free to use and works on Linux only

By the way: What's wrong with Inkscape using CTRL as Control-Key?

Comment: CTRL is the least of my worries with Inkscape, it also fires up X11, has a UI that, as a longtime user of vector programs (Illustrator, before that Freehand) is just counter intuitive. Needs its UI fixed.